# How to programmatically instantiate dynamically loaded class from values in a file?

Tags: java, testing, reflection, mongodb, morphia

I have basic knowledge of Java's reflection API - therefore, this is not only a question of how, it's a question of whether it's possible and whether I'm going about a solution the best way.

We're doing some *acceptance testing* of multiple, interrelated projects; each of these projects retrieve data from a MongoDB store using an in-house abstraction API. To facilitate this testing, each component needs some pre-loaded data to be available in the database.

I'm building a command-line tool to accept a DTO (pre-compiled class binary), for loading of multiple instances using the morphia ORM library. I would like each member of our team to be able to run the generator passing in via cli their DTO (in jar or directory form), and a file (csv or otherwise) for instantiating a desired amount of records.

I have the class loading working fine with `URLClassLoader`. Now I'm trying to instantiate an instance of this class using data from a file.

Is this possible? Would serialized objects be a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly possible using the Java Reflection API :

- Load Class instance by name (Class.forName(className), you don't really need the ClassLoader instance)
- Grab Constructor instance of constructors have parameters and invoke newInstance(Object... args) on this constructor instance to create an instance of your DTO class.
- Invoke getDeclaredFields() on your Class instance and iterate over them to set their values (field.set(instance, value)). Make sure to invoke field.setAccessible(true) to be able to access private fields.

Comment: I'm using `URLClassLoader` because it accepts an array of `URL` which enables me to load a class (using `File`) external to my applications jar file; unless you can think of a nicer way?

Comment: No that works if you want to test classes in JAR files that aren't in your codebase paths.

Answer (score 0):

If by "serialized objects" you mean canned instances, then no, by loading properties from a text file you allow much easier tweaking of test data (if that's a goal), including the number of objects.

But sure, it's possible; unmarshal the data from the input file and use it to initialize or construct the object in question like you would in regular code.

Comment: looks like yaml might be a good solution for creating serialized instances that are readily _tweaked_.